# What's the default password for SYSTEM in Amazon Oracle RDS?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, aws

I can only remember setting these parameters and definitely not the password for SYSTEM:

1. DB Instance Identifier = mydbinstanceidentifier
2. Master Username = mymasterusername
3. Master Password = mymasterpassword

Comment: Yes i've tried, but to no avail..

Comment: I use this query "SELECT * FROM dba_users;" the account_status is open for SYSTEM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The SYS user, SYSTEM user, and other administrative accounts are locked and cannot be used
>   [More](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html)

The Amazon documentation for Oracle on Amazon RDS says you have to use master user which has the `DBA` privilege and other users like `SYS` and `SYSTEM` are locked by default and cannot be used.

`SYSDBA` privilege is not available for customer in Amazon RDS so Amazon EC2 might be a better choice for you and can have full control over the database and high privileged user like `SYS` and `SYSTEM` user.

Useful links:

[Best Practices for Running Oracle Database on Amazon Web Services](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/best-practices-for-running-oracle-database-on-aws.pdf)

[Common DBA Tasks for Oracle DB Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.html)

[Oracle on Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html)

Comment: This is quite frustrating... I'm running IBM MobileFirst application setup and it prompts for SYSTEM password by default... Hope there's a way to access the system user